# C# Linq Where Clause on Nested List Attribute

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

I have a class `Proforma` which contains a List of type MonthlyPayment. Here is the code:

```
public class Proforma 
{
    List<MonthlyPayment> lstMonthlyPayment = new List<MonthlyPayment>();
    // Other Attributes
}

List<Proforma> lstProforma = Fetch();
```

Now I want to select those records from `lstProforma` where `lstMonthlyPayment.Month==DateTime.Now.Month`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you store `MonthlyPayment.Month` as `DateTime` and use it's `Month` property if you need that or the `Year` property if you need that? However, do not store it as string, all the more if you store typos like `Feburary`.

Comment: coz monthly Payment contains other attributes too

Comment: No problem, then use other properties too. But i think you didn't get my point. `Month` is a  string property  but its better to store datetimes.

Comment: yes you r right it is actually integer i will edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a linq query like:

```
 var query = from proforma in lstProforma
             from payment in proforma.lstMonthlyPayment
             where payment.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
             select proforma;
```

As Tim pointed out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074974/c-sharp-linq-where-clause-on-nested-list-attribute#comment48263581_30075027), you should not use a string for Month as your code could be prone to issues and typos. You should use a `DateTime` property (`Date` for example in the class MonthlyPayment) or an integer.

Comment: Your answer was correct as far as i can tell. I just wanted to point out that OP is looking for records where the list contains a `Month="Feburary"` not `"February"`. A property `Month` should be `int` or `DateTime` but not string. Otherwise it's open for localization issues and typos.

Comment: Oh I see now. Well it's not clear what his data-structure is for Month, so I assumed it was a string. Thanks for pointing it out though I haven't thought about localization issue

Comment: how can we get result into List<Proforma> ? ( i am new in LINQ )

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal: `query.ToList()`